# Running multiple remote access instances of IPython with different profiles on the same port but accessed with different urls

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am currently running a single instance of a notebook set up for secure remote access on port 443 (https://example.com/ipython/). I would like to allow others to have access, but not to my main notebook. Is it possible to spawn multiple instances listening on the same port but with different url prefixes (such as /ipython-school/, /ipython-shared/, etc)? (as outlined [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html#running-with-a-different-url-prefix))

Answer (score 1):

No it is a general technical limitation. You cannot have multiple app listening on the same port. You will have to rely on something that act as a [proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/ipython-notebook-proxy) an forward request to multiple instance that listen on localhost on different port.